# 16.04 - Is it possible to speed up kernel boot time?

Tags: boot, kernel

I am working on trying to get my boot up time as short as possible.  I have done several changes that got my time from 3 minutes down to about 14 seconds.  All of the changes seem to affect the userspace startup portion.  The one thing that I noticed remains constant is the kernel startup speed.  `systemd-analyze` gives me the following results:

```
Startup finished in 11.162s (kernel) + 3.239s (userspace) = 14.402s
```

I have tried setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT=1` in **/etc/default/grub** but that did not influence the startup time for the kernel.

I am running 16.04 on a Lenovo U510 with a 1TB hybrid drive, no other OS on board.  Thanks!

Comment: Some linux distros are better for this. Gentoo for example.  Load fewer modules on boot, and boot time should decrease.  grub doesn't have much to do with the kernel. perhaps migrate this to Unix & linux SE

Comment: The only way is to build your own kernel . The benefits will be modest at best.

Comment: 14 seconds is great!  Congrats!  Don't change anything!

Comment: Thanks, always looking to improve though, kind of the Millennium Falcon approach; keep tweaking it until I break/learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim down the initramfs to speed up boot by editing /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf and setting `MODULES=dep`.

Then run the following to update the initramfs to hopefully make a smaller one:

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: That seemed to work! My new startup numbers are `Startup finished in 10.685s (kernel) + 2.321s (userspace) = 13.006s` When I did the update I had to add "-u" to the end for it to work, so `sudo update-initramfs -u` , do you know why that is?

Comment: Sorry, my instructions were wrong, you do need a -u to trigger the update. I'll update the instructions. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize kernel boot (init) time you have to compile your own kernel tailored to your specific hardware. You can enable `initcall_debug`on the kernel command line to get some details printed in the kernel log. The `bootgraph.pl`script from the kernel sources will help you to get a quick overview of the time spent inside the kernel. Disable unneeded kernel options. Turn other built-in into modules and load later in user-space in parallel. Focus on the long running ones first, which you can detect using `dmesg | grep initcall | sort -k8 -n`.