# Xubuntu 16.04 boot very slow

Tags: boot

Hello i have a hp laptop and my xubuntu (i came from arch) boot very slowly
The output of systemd anlyze is:
Startup finished in 4.963s (firmware) + 51.096s (loader) + 7.833s (kernel) + 26.792s (userspace) = 1min 30.686s

Why loader takes a lot of time to load, and how can i fix this?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Try using `systemd-analyze blame` or `systemd-analyze plot > startup.svg` where you can view the whole startup by opening the `startup.svg` file with an image viewer that will show you a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this advice? [16.04 - Is it possible to speed up kernel boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878041/16-04-is-it-possible-to-speed-up-kernel-boot-time)

> "You can trim down the initramfs to speed up boot by editing **/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf** and setting **MODULES=dep**.
>   Then run the following to update the initramfs to hopefully make a smaller one:
>   **sudo update-initramfs -u**"